# How to build a graph based on a Voronoi diagram?

Tags: graph, voronoi

I have a set of points with x and y coordinates. I would like to build a Voronoi diagram from these points, and then build a graph based on this diagram, with the following rules:

- Each region from the diagram will become a node in the graph.
- Two nodes are connected if their regions touch each other in the diagram.

How do I build this graph? I just a need a starting point, so I know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

The graph you are looking for is the [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation), which is the dual of the Voronoi diagram. In this graph, nodes correspond the points in the input and nodes are connected in the graph/triangulation if the associated Voronoi cells touch each other.

You can build the Delaunay triangulation in scipy using [scipy.spatial.Delaunay](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html). The data you are looking for (which vertices are connected to each other) is available through the [vertex_neighbor_vertices attribute](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.vertex_neighbor_vertices.html#scipy.spatial.Delaunay.vertex_neighbor_vertices) of the result.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> points = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1.1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])
>>> from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
>>> tri = Delaunay(points)
>>> tri.vertex_neighbor_vertices
(array([ 0,  3,  5,  7, 10], dtype=int32), array([2, 3, 1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1], dtype=int32))
```

In the above example, the graph connectivity is stored using two array: the second containing all the neighboring vertices and the first containing the ranges of positions in the each corresponding to each particular vertex. The verticies are numbered: 0=[0,0], 1=[0,1.1], 2=[1,0], 3=[1,1]). Then in the resulting graph, vertex 0 is connected to vertices 2, 3, and 1 (in positions 0, 1, and 3 in the second array), vertex 1 is connected to vertices 3 and 0 (n positions 3 and 4 in the second array), vertex 2 is connected to vertices 3 and 0 and vertex 3 is connected to vertices 2, 0, and 1.

From the scipy doc, triangulation is shown below: vertices 0 and 3 have three neighbors and the other two vertices only have two neighbors.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for. Do you know a library for that in C#? I'm asking this because I need to implement this inside the Unity engine.

Comment: I would suggest starting with Triangle.NET (a C# port of Triangle), looking at the discussion on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17461344/6469634